# Proximity.PeerFinder.Start() error

Tags: windows-phone-8, runtime-error, nfc

I am using a shared class to create NFC connectivity in a Win 8 app and a Win Phone 8 app. When I run the apps, I get the following error in the line  Windows.Networking.Proximity.PeerFinder.Start(); in the Phone app
The error shown is the below:

Any ideas why I am getting this error? I do not get this error in the windows 8 app. I am following the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh465205(v=win.10).aspx

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2147024809
Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.
Source=Windows
StackTrace:
   at Windows.Networking.Proximity.PeerFinder.Start()
   at NFCTabApp.PeerConnector.AdvertiseForPeers()
   at NFCPhoneApp.MainPage.AdvertiseForPeersButton_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
InnerException:
```